# React native code update

Tags: react-native, expo

I published my first app to AppStore last night.

I just want to know if there is code change in my app,

Should I have to re-build and upload .ipa file to itunes connect again?
(Currently, I do not use CodePush and I build app with exp)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Expo comes with a built in CodePush equivalent.
Whenever you `publish` to expo (using `exp publish`, the XDE etc), expo builds new JS bundles and uploads them to their servers.
Users who downloaded the app from the stores will get those updates - while iOS users will get them as soon as they open the app, Android users will get them in the second time (iOS is does this syncly while Android asyncly).

Note that this does not apply to changes in the app config (`app.json`), including sdk upgrades or any other configuration changes.

Comment: You mean that if I want to change app's name(in app.json), I have to upload new ipa file. Right?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you will need to rebuild the release version of your app and upload to the App Store as a new version.